# echo php variable in javascript leafletjs openstreetmaps

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, leaflet

I'm echoing out an openstreetmaps set to a certain latitude and longitude with leafletjs.

I'm getting the custom fields from the backend as so :

```
$longitude = the_field('longitude','option');

$latitude = the_field('latitude','option');
```

I initialise leaflet on the next line with

```
var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: 0.16033, lat: 52.12676}, 17);
```

I want to replace what comes after lon: with $longitude and what comes after lat: with $latitude.

I have tried putting my php in "" to make sure it is interpreted correctly in javascript. I have used json_encode($longitude) but I am getting errors such as "NaN" in the console.

Weirdly, when I check for NaN I get 'false', which I believe indicates that I am correctly getting a number from the backend , which I want to use to set the long and lat for the map in javascript.

`console.log(isNaN("<?php echo $longitude; ?>"));`

It works when I hard code a number but not when pulling in these variables.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could echo the whole javascript with php... if the script has double quotes escape them.Something like this...

```
<?php
$longitude = the_field('longitude','option');

$latitude = the_field('latitude','option');

echo  "<script> //code var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: $longitude, lat: $latitude}, 17); //code </script>";


?>
```

To escape double quotes just add \ before every double quote.